# Return a concatenated value from a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Please advise me to get the return value as 4/30 from a stored procedure.
I have declared a stored procedure with one output parameter @result varchar(5) output and no input parameter,
I have declared 3 variables inside a stored procedure say

```
declare @a float
declare @b float
declare @c varchar  

set @a=4
 set @b=30
set  @c=cast(@a as varchar)+'/'+cast(@b as varchar)

set @result=@c
return @result
```

The stored procedure executes and returns the return value as 4.
But I need the return value to be 4/30. Is it possible to get 4/30 as return value? 
Please suggest me on the above...

Actually I want to set @a to a select query which returns a float number,
and set @b to another select query which returns a float number .. but in the above sp just showed an example. Please advise me to get the return value as 4/30.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a size for `@c`. Without size it will be `varchar(1)`.

```
declare @c varchar(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the length parameter when declaring the variable @c

```
declare @c varchar(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing down query in MS,the thing i clear about is that there is need to specify variable length of variable.....

```
declare @a int;
declare @b int;
declare @c varchar(5);
set @a=4;
set @b=30;
SET @c=cast(@a as varchar)+'/'+cast(@b as varchar)
select @c;
```